# How to plot a 3D function with colors given spacing 2D input

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, matplotlib-3d

Let's assume I have 3 arrays defined as:

```
v1=np.linspace(1,100)
v2=np.linspace(1,100)
v3=np.linspace(1,100)
```

Then I have a function that takes those 3 values and gives me the desired output, let's assume it is like:

f = (v1 + v2*10)/v3

I want to plot that function on a 3D plot with axis v1,v2,v3 and color it's surface depending on its value.
More than the best way to plot it, I was also interested in how to scroll all the values in the in vectors and build the function point by point.
I have been trying with for loops inside other for loops but I am always getting one error.

MANY THANKS

I tried this but i'm always getting a line instead of a surface

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, Function

# Parameters I use in the function
L = 132
alpha = 45*math.pi/180
beta = 0


s,t = symbols('s,t')
z = Function('z')(s,t)
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

# experiment with various range of data in x and y
x1 = np.linspace(-40,-40,100)  
y1 = np.linspace(-40,40,100)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)

# My function Z
c1=math.cos(beta)**2
c2=math.cos(alpha)**2
s1=math.sin(alpha)**2
den = math.sqrt((c1*c2)+s1)
z=L*((math.cos(beta)/den)-1)+(s*(math.sin(alpha)))+(t*(1-math.cos(alpha)))


ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,cmap='rainbow')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example I'm going to show you how to achieve your goal. Specifically, I use Numpy because it supports vectorized operations, hence I avoid `for` loops.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Parameters I use in the function
L = 132
alpha = 45*np.pi/180
beta = 0

figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

# experiment with various range of data in x and y
x1 = np.linspace(-40,40,100)  
y1 = np.linspace(-40,40,100)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)

# My function Z
c1=np.cos(beta)**2
c2=np.cos(alpha)**2
s1=np.sin(alpha)**2
den = np.sqrt((c1*c2)+s1)
z=L*((np.cos(beta)/den)-1)+(x*(np.sin(alpha)))+(y*(1-np.cos(alpha)))

# compute the color values according to some other function
color_values = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
# normalize color values between 0 and 1
norm = Normalize(vmin=color_values.min(), vmax=color_values.max())
norm_color_values = norm(color_values)
# chose a colormap and create colors starting from the normalized values
cmap = cm.rainbow
colors = cmap(norm_color_values)

surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,facecolors=colors)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
# add a colorbar
figure.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), label="radius")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! this works great. I just cannot show the colorbar as I get: "Unable to determine Axes to steal space for Colorbar. Either provide the cax argument to use as the Axes for the Colorbar, provide the ax argument to steal space from it, or add mappable to an Axes."

I think is a python or matplotlib version bug that could be solved by downgrading it (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23709/) but is not working for me :(

Comment: which matplotlib version are you using? `import matplotlib;print(matplotlib.__version__)`

Comment: Now I have 3.6.0

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Use this: `figure.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax, label="radius")`